# Django templates exclude field from form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-bootstrap3

I'm working with `django-bootstrap4`. I want to exclude one field from form. How can I do that with `bootstrap4`.

**my view:**

```
{% for item in form %}
        {% cycle 'row' '' as row silent %}
        {% if row %}
        <div class="row">{% endif %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {% bootstrap_field item exclude=item.insured_type %}
            </div>
            {% if not row %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I read the documentation and `bootstrap_field` have `exclude` parameter but I have no idea how to use that. I wanted to `exclude` field that name `insured_type`.

Comment: The django way is to use minimal logic in templates. I think you are probably better off with creating a form that has only the fields that you require

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple.

```
{% bootstrap_field item exclude="insured_type" form_group_class="col-md-6 form-group" %}
```